# Use of float in HTML

Tags: html, css

Having a problem in setting the right margin on a web page and using float.
Want all the 3 sections to come in a single row when viewing in desktop and to have right margin at section 3.
https://chawlaji8781.github.io/module2-solution/index.html
https://chawlaji8781.github.io/module2-solution/CSS/style.css

Comment: Because of your margins on the sections, you have to compensate for it on the width of each section. Try reducing the with from `width:33.33%` to maybe `width:31%`

Answer (score 3):

wrap your sections with a div with a class. and use that class to display it as flex. Here's the demo code.

```
<div class="row">
<section id="s1">
    <h2 id="d1">Chicken</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit error quis ab perspiciatis eos inventore recusandae iste itaque numquam facilis, tenetur. Doloribus officiis quae facilis, nisi, ex similique. Animi, perferendis.</p>
</section>
<section id="s2">
    <h2 id="d2">Beef</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit error quis ab perspiciatis eos inventore recusandae iste itaque numquam facilis, tenetur. Doloribus officiis quae facilis, nisi, ex similique. Animi, perferendis.</p>
</section>
<section id="s3">
    <h2 id="d3">Sushi</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit error quis ab perspiciatis eos inventore recusandae iste itaque numquam facilis, tenetur. Doloribus officiis quae facilis, nisi, ex similique. Animi, perferendis.</p>
</section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer. But they will stay inline if i change the width of the browser also. I dont want that. I only want this for desktop view

Comment: use the media query for desktop only. It's as easy as that.

Answer (score 1):

because you have to understand how `box-sizing` property works:

when you give the `section` a width of `33.3%` you may think this meaning 3 * 33.3 = 99.9 so the three sections will be on the same row but you missed the **margin** of sections that you should take in account

every section have 15px left and 15px right and this mean the 3 sections have 30 * 3 = 90px you should subtract from total width

so the final calculation should be similar to this snippet below :

```
section {
width: calc((100% - 90px) /3);
}
```

- 100% = full width
- 90px = total margin of the 3 sections

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="holder">

            <div class="1">
                    <div class="s1">
                       <h2 id="d1">Chicken</h2>
                         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit error quis ab perspiciatis eos inventore recusandae iste itaque numquam facilis, tenetur. Doloribus officiis quae facilis, nisi, ex similique. Animi, perferendis.</p>

                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="2">
                    <div class="s2">
                        <h2 id="d2">Beef</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit error quis ab perspiciatis eos inventore recusandae iste itaque numquam facilis, tenetur. Doloribus officiis quae facilis, nisi, ex similique. Animi, perferendis.</p>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="3">
                    <div class="s3">
                        <h2 id="d3">Sushi</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit error quis ab perspiciatis eos inventore recusandae iste itaque numquam facilis, tenetur. Doloribus officiis quae facilis, nisi, ex similique. Animi, perferendis.</p> 
                    </div>
            </div>

</div>



<-----------------------------------

.holder {
    padding-bottom: 6vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}
```

try this any errors let me know